# Composer Install Runtime Exception

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to create a fresh laravel setup. When I run `composer install` I get an error that doesn't give me much information and I don't really know how to solve it.

**Here's the error**

```
$ composer install
```

> php artisan
>
> clear-compiled Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output:

**This is my composer.json file**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Hope any of you guys can help me out!

Comment: try to clear composer cache and run composer update:
composer clearcache

Comment: @AhmedAtta Tried this, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As of a recent change in `composer`, you should move `php artisan clear-compiled` to the `post-update-command` key.

https://laravel-news.com/2016/03/may-need-update-composer-json-file